# Internal Error Message in Drupal when saving edits

Tags: drupal, internal-server-error

My site is built with `Drupal 7.19`.

When I make an edit to a page, I get this message:

**The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.**

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@xxxxxx.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

I checked my log messages, and I noticed I have many, many "page not found" with a message of `"favicon.ico"`. I found this info but it did not fix: http://web3us.com/drupal6/how-create-web-site-handbook/how-setup-drupal-5/how-fix-faviconico-page-not-found-drupal

The edits to the page are reflected, but why this message? There is no 404 or 500 associated.

Comment: This issue remains unsolved...can anyone point me to general internal server error information? I don't have programming skills so any advice on how to start is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The missing favicon has nothing to do with the Internal Server error. The most likely issues is that your PHP memory limit is too low. 
Drupal 7 suggested memory limit is 128MB. You can change the limit in your settings.php file in the default (sites/default/settings.php) folder by adding the following line:

ini_set('memory_limit','128M');

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried your suggestion, but same problem exists. I only get this message when I edit a page via Content>Edit Page but not when I navigate to a Page>Edit.